# SQL Search Syntax Error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I cant see where my syntax error is, it all looks fine from what I can see, tried looking around stack and everything looks fine.

Error (Query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'like '%no search%'' at line 1)

```
    if (isset($_POST["find"]) && !empty($_POST["find"])) {
        $find = $_POST["find"];
        $find = strtoupper($find); 
        $find = strip_tags($find); 
        $find = trim ($find); 

    }else{  
        $find = "no search";
    }


    DB::init(); 
    $result = DB::Query("SELECT * FROM products  like '%$find%' ");
    if(!$result) {
        die("Query failed: ".DB::LastError());  
    }
    if($result->num_rows ==0 ) {    
    }

    $result_list = array();

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
           $result_list[] = $row;
    }
```

Any help much thanked :)

Comment: table name is fine, i can get all the results to show when I remove the like '%$find%'

Comment: where condition is missing....

Comment: sorry me being stupid, i thought you could search all the columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you miss the `WHERE` condition?

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE <column name> LIKE'%$find%'
```

Answer (score 2):

Where condition is missing in your query.....

```
SELECT * FROM <TableName> WHERE <ColumnName> LIKE condition
```

Answer (score 1):

there is no where clause

```
SELECT * FROM products  LIKE'%$find%'
```

should become something like

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE name LIKE'%$find%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the column name in the condition

just try

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE <column name> LIKE '%$find%'
```

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE` and [column name] are missing

```
 SELECT * FROM products WHERE [column name] LIKE '%$find%'
```